# React Bootstrap table doesn't show properly

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-4

My goal is to create a table with React Bootstrap. To start with, I have used following [example](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/table/).

**Now I have the following problem**:
Instead of the header line of the table being above everything, it is suddenly to the left of the body. I have taken the code exactly as in the example and therefore don't know why this happens.

[image: image of the table]

I use the react-bootstrap version: `1.5.2` and have imported the CSS in the class index.js like this `import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';`.

And this is the code I copied from the page and inserted in my code 1:1.

```
                <Table striped bordered hover>
                    <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>#</th>
                        <th>First Name</th>
                        <th>Last Name</th>
                        <th>Username</th>
                    </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>1</td>
                        <td>Mark</td>
                        <td>Otto</td>
                        <td>@mdo</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>2</td>
                        <td>Jacob</td>
                        <td>Thornton</td>
                        <td>@fat</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>3</td>
                        <td colSpan="2">Larry the Bird</td>
                        <td>@twitter</td>
                    </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </Table>
```

How can I fix this and what was the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Have you imported table?

```
import Table from 'react-bootstrap/Table'
```

See bottom of documentation to learn more:
https://react-bootstrap.netlify.app/components/table/#table-api

Comment: I've imported the Table like this `import {Button, Form, Table} from "react-bootstrap";`, does this make a difference?